# Where should I add a List All Users function when using MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm aware that in [model-view-controller](/questions/tagged/model-view-controller), the Model is the class part.

If I have a User class and instantiate an object, the object must refer to a single user from the database.

So I'll have the CRUD methods on the user, for that specific user.

But if I need a function to run a `SELECT * FROM Users`, should I create a function within the User class? Or a function in a helper file? Or in the controller? Where should it go, in order to respect the MVC pattern?

I mean, it makes no sense to instantiate a User object just to run a function to display the Users table.

---

<sup>I'm not sure if this will raise "primarily opinion based" flags. I just don't know where those functions should go. If you guys consider the question worth closing, it's ok. But tell me in the comments in which stack community I should ask this.</sup>

Comment: Add a project, called DataLayer or whatever to your project.  Use the factory pattern for this, returning an instance of your DataClass, for Instance, to return the UserDataAccess class.  This should be accessed in your ViewModel, and call the necessary functions from there. Works pretty sweet. Let me know if you need an example.

Answer (score 1):

Back up a bit. Let's go foundational for a moment.

In the MVC pattern

- The model is your state (in simple terms), meaning a representation of the data important to the business functionality you are working with
- The view is a way of presenting the state to the user (NOTE user here could be another system, as you can use MVC patterns for service endpoints)
- The controller ensures the model gets to the view and back out of the view

In a system designed with good separation of state, business functions are not present in the model, the view or the controller. You segregate business functionality into its own class library. Why? You never know when the application will require a mobile (native, not web) implementation or a desktop implementation or maybe even become part of a windows service.

As for getting at data, proper separation of concerns states the data access is separate not only from the model, view and controller, but also from the business functionality. This is why DALs are created.

Before going on, let's go to your questions.

should I create a function within the User class? This is an "active record" pattern, which is largely deprecated today, as it closely couples behavior and state. I am sure there are still some instances where it applies, but I would not use it.

Or a function in a helper file? Better option, as you can separate it out. But I am not fond of "everything in a single project" approach, personally.

Or in the controller? Never, despite Scott Gu's first MVC examples where he put LINQ to SQL (another groan?) in the controller.

Where should it go, in order to respect the MVC pattern?

Here is my suggestion:

- Create a DAL project to access the data. One possible pattern that works nicely here is the repository pattern. If you utilize the same data type for your keys in all/most tables, you can create a generic repository and then derive individual versions for specific data. Okay, so this one is really old, but looking over it, it still has the high level concepts (https://gregorybeamer.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/generics-on-the-data-access-layer)
- Create a core project for the business logic, if needed. I do this every time, as it allows me to test the ideas on the DAL through unit tests. Yes, I can test directly in the MVC project (and do), but I like a clean separation as you rarely find 0% business rules in a solution.
- Have the core pull the data from the DAL project and the MVC project use the core project. Nice flow. Easy to unit test. etc.

If you want this in a single project, then separate out the bits into different folders so you can make individual projects, if needed, in the future.

Answer (score 1):

For the love of all things good and holy, *don't* use the repository pattern. @GregoryABeamer has a great answer in all respects, except recommending you create repository instances to access your entities. Your ORM (most likely Entity Framework) covers this, and *completely* replaces the concepts of repositories and unit of work.

Simply, if you need something from your database, hit your ORM directly in your controller. If you prefer, you can still add a level of abstraction to hide the use of the ORM itself, such that you could more easily switch out the data access with another ORM, Web Api, etc. Just don't do a traditional unit of work with tens or hundreds of repository instances. If you're interested, you can [read a series of posts I wrote about that on my blog](http://cpratt.co/truly-generic-repository). I use the term "repository" with my approach, but mostly just to contrast with the typical "generic" repository approach you find scattered all over the interwebs.

Comment: I know that it's all made easier using EF. You would simply run a `obj.ToList()` IIRC. But if I want to make my own data retrieval function. In which layer should it go? That's the question.

Comment: Also. Hitting the ORM directly from the controller, I'm not so sure if that's the correct approach. I tought that the controller should control user input, and that everything database related would come from the model layer, and sent to the controller with a single function.

Comment: In MVC, the pattern, not just the framework from Microsoft, the Controller is responsible for wiring up the view, whatever that entails. Even with the active record approach of something like RoR, the actual querying logic may be in the Model, but the Controller is still the actor that initiates the DB queries. ASP.NET MVC (the framework) is not like RoR, though, and only loosely follows the MVC pattern (despite the name). The Model in ASP.NET MVC is not just one thing, but really a combination of your entity class, your DAL (the ORM or your abstraction thereof) and view models.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use some kind of 'Repository' layer. Then, my controller calls the UserRepository GetAll method and sends the data to View layer.